# Ionic2: Translating the File-Chooser uri to File path

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic native provides the File Chooser and File plugin separately. The File plugin requires the absolute path of the file to read, but provides no way to *pick* the file.

In order to pick the file, I used File Chooser, which returns a URI.

```
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';

constructor(private fileChooser: FileChooser) { }

...

this.fileChooser.open()
  .then(uri => console.log(uri))
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

The uri looks something like this

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A68
```

The File Plugin can read a file by utilizing the path.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private file: File) { }

...

this.file.readAsText(this.file.dataDirectory, 'myFile')
.then((content) =>
       console.log(this.file.dataDirectory + 'myFile');
       console.log(content)
).catch( err => 
       console.log('File doesnt exist')
);
```

The path looks like this.

```
file:///data/data/com.myapp.myappmobile/files/myFile
```

How do I utilize both the components. Pick a file using FileChooser and Then read it with in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kindly install the FilePath plugin to get the native path.
Then use the below code.
Say for example you are choosing an image file.

```
nativepath: any;
uploadfn(){
   this.fileChooser.open().then((url) => {
  (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, (result) => {
    this.nativepath = result;
    this.readimage();
  }
  )
})
}  

readimage() {
    (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.nativepath, (res) => {
      res.file((resFile) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
        reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
          var imgBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg'});
          //do what you want to do with the file
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Kindly have a look here - http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-serving-images-with-firebase-storage/

(Deals with how to choose an image from the phone's filesystem and upload it onto firebase storage)

Hope this helped you. Thanks.

Comment: It worked. I wonder though! Why does the file chooser return a uri. Where exactly are uri's used?

Comment: FilePath is only supported on Android, how do you resolve the filePath on IOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Using FilePath:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';

constructor(
    private fileChooser: FileChooser,
    private filePath: FilePath
) {

}

private captureFile(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.fileChooser.open().then((uri) => {

                this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri)
                    .then((filePath) => {
                        alert(filePath)                      
                    }, (err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    })
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });

        });

    }
```